# interactive function: Meaning of Does not do I/O

Tags: help, interactive

I'm going through the documentation for the `interactive` function and there are some code letters which are documented like this:

```
d -- Value of point as number.  Does not do I/O.
P -- Prefix arg in raw form.  Does not do I/O.
```

My question is what does it mean when it mentions "Does not do I/O" ? We have the function `recompile` which uses `(interactive "P")`. The `recompile` function also uses the variable `compile-command` whose default value is this:

```
(defcustom compile-command (purecopy "make -k ")
```

Now I believe executing `make` command is actually a form of I/O as it involves spawning new process, possibly creating object files. But probably I'm mis-understanding how it's used in the context of Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that it doesn’t prompt the user for any information.